# import file from different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import a file from another directory but it's not working.

```
App
|___init__.py
|_notebooks
| |__init__.py
| |_test.py
|_src
| |___init__.py
| |_loss.py
```

I want to import loss in test.py.
I have tried

`from src import loss` --> which is giving me no module named src error

`from .src import loss` and `from ..src import loss` --> gives attempted relative import with no known parent package

```
sys.path.insert(0, '../src/')
import loss
```

is working but I want to do it without using sys. so that there won't be any headache in the production and I believe its possible.
i have gone through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) but none of the solutions seems to be working.

Comment: You need to understand how python discoveres modules. The solution is to make your package installable, then to install it. Then it doesn't matter what your working directory is, it will be discovered on import (usually by being put into site-packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute test.py in a way that makes Python aware of the src folder. That is, `python notebooks/test.py` won't work because Python will take the location of your script (i.e. the notebooks folder) as starting point for imports. This explains the `attempted relative import with no known parent package` error.

To fix it, call it with its package structure included: `python -m notebooks.test`, you can then use `from src import loss`.